# How to explore Dynamics NAV Native Database?

Tags: database, odbc, native, nav, microsoft-dynamics

I have to prepare some queries and export data from Dynamics NAV Native Database.

I have an ODBC driver installed that connects to the database but I don't know how to explore it and check tables and data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to explorer a NAV Database would be the [Object Designer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd301170(v=nav.60).aspx) (in the Menu **Tools** -> **Object Designer**) inside the Dynamics NAV Client. You can open every table with **Run**.

Answer (score 0):

Please let me know what version of NAV you have. If you are using RTC, in any page you should be able to go to the "about to" page and see the table and the all of its fields. If you are using NAV classic, you will have to hit ctrl + f2 in order  to go to the designer mode and right click on the fields and view their properties.